# How to use signalr hub function in Url.Action?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I created a function in my signalr hub class and I want to use this function after click on Url.Action in my view.

I tried to do that in this way: This is my function in `Hub` Class

```
public void AddNewUserMessage(string toUser)
{
    var toUserName = _dbContext.Users.Where(x => x.Id == toUser).Select(y => y.UserName).ToString();
    var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    var userId = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();
    Clients.Client(toUser).onNewUserConnected(userId, name);
    Clients.Caller.onNewUserConnected(toUser, toUserName);
}
```

And this is my `Url.Action`:

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Chat" , new {onclick= "chatHub.server.addNewUserMessage("+item.Id+");" })" aria-label="Go to chat">
<i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i></a>
```

Is it possible that it work in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example needs to use the `$.connection` object when referring to the `chatHub`, and use the `client` object instead of `server` when invoking server methods.  Please see MSDN here: https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#callserver

> Also, don't embed JavaScript in your markup.  It makes things difficult to maintain.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Chat", new { onclick= "$.connection.chatHub.client.addNewUserMessage("+item.Id+");" })">
    <i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i>
</a>
```